# How to configure properties for evosuite maven plugin in the pom file?

Tags: maven, evosuite

I need to set a property for evosuite through maven. The property is `assertion_strategy` and I want to set it to `all`

I tried to pass it through the maven commandm didn't work.
I also tried to set it through the pom, but I guess I'm not using the right tags

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>evosuite-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.evosuite.plugins</groupId>
                <version>${evosuiteVersion}</version>
                <configuration>
                 <properties>
                   <property>
                      <name>assertion_strategy</name>
                      <value>all</value>
                  </property>
                 </properties>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
</plugin>
```

I expect to see -Dassertion_strategy=all when I'm looking at the evosuite jar execution within the maven debug mode command.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `-DextraArgs="-Dassertion_strategy=all"` on Maven command line to check if it really works?

Comment: Thanks. Tried, not working